# display table using where condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display the table using where condition on id column, but when I run the query the query, the table displays without where condition

```
Table: test

id  name
1   aaa
2   bbb
3   ccc
```

I want to display the table like below :

```
Select * from test where id in ('2','3','1')
```

when I run the above query it is displayed as failing where condition.

```
1. aaa
2. bbb
3. ccc
```

Comment: How is it failing? - were you expecting output to be in the order of the in clause?

Comment: yes , I want it to be displayed in order of the in clause.

Comment: Yes @P.Salmon 's duplicate works assuming you don't want to query `in (2,2,3,1)` and get two id 2 records.. Your expected results does not show this so i don't know if this is a feature.

Comment: Thanks Maxim, ORDER BY IN solved my issue partially . I have 100 column id's I want to display 55, 21, 36, 47  first and then all the id's respectively , Do I have write all the id's in the ORDER BY In clause.

Answer (score 0):

try below query

```
select * from test 
  where id in (2,3,1) 
  order by 
    case id
      when 2 then 1
      when 3 then 2
      when 1 then 3
    end
```

here is the [link for db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8eRVhax7sHcsWHaYJDsEn/0)

Comment: isn;t this pretty hardcoded?

Comment: yes it is. but it seems fine to me as i am a bit high -)) look at the indentation - isn't it pretty? -))

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    test
WHERE
    id in ('2','3','1')
ORDER BY FIELD(id,'2','3','1');
```